# Update android notification with new line is removing previous lines

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to group notifications into a summary.

I achieve this by having a single ID for all notifications. This way android will not create new notifications but update the existing one (reduced code):

```
Notification summaryNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setGroupSummary(true)
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle()
            .addLine(msg)
            .setBigContentTitle("My App")
            .setSummaryText("FooBar"))
    .build();

mNotificationManager.notify(uuid, summaryNotification);
```

UUID is always the same so that the notification should be updated. However when a new notification arrives, `setStyle` seems to be overwritten.

This cause the old `addLine(msg)` to disappear. However I want the new message to be added without having some kind of notification manager server side.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: How you are generating UUID

Comment: @RajnishMishra int uuid = 1;

Comment: Are you calling  builder.setNumber(messages.size());

Comment: @RajnishMishra no I am not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are misinterpreting the notification builder.

The NotificationCompat.Builder builds the *complete* notification, with all the content.
Reusing the same id simply tells the notification manager to replace an existing notification with the same id with the new one: ([Source](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Updating))

> [...] update or create a NotificationCompat.Builder object, build a Notification object from it, and issue the Notification with the same ID you used previously. If the previous notification is still visible, the system updates it *from the contents of the Notification object*.

Thus `addLine` is not an operation that is performed on an existing notification, but on the new builder you created (which is empty at that time).

If you want to add a line to an existing notification with the inbox style, you will need to either

- keep the original builder object, add lines as needed and resend the notification with the same id
- create a new builder and add the old lines first, then the new one. You will need to store or retrieve the old lines from somewhere (depending on your application).

Comment: I create notifications from a gcm service, just like in the android gcm tutorial. Is it safe to keep an instance of notification builder in this service rather creating a new?

Comment: If you use an IntentService as described in the tutorial, I would advise against it: "IntentService will receive the Intents, launch a worker thread, and stop the service as appropriate."
Thus your instance might go away - and with it your builder. You might want to think about how to persist the data you previously passed to the builder. Or - if you control the server - just send a reasonable subset of the old data along with the notification.